# Como pegar o total de registro de uma tabela

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Preciso saber quantos registros existem dentro de minha tabela e adicionar o total achado em uma variável. Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira mas não dá certo:

```
   <?php
        $w_querybusca = "SELECT * FROM Elem_matr;";
        $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);

        $result = pg_num_rows($w_queryresultado);
        echo $result;        
    ?>
```

Deveria fazer de qual maneira?

O problema é: Com esse exemplo acima ele só mostra que a valores dentro da tabela. O que eu preciso é do total contido dentro dessa tabela!

Comment: Estou utilizando o PostgreSQL

Comment: Pode descrever melhor o que não funciona? da erro? de um `print_r` em `$w_queryresultado`

Comment: Bem, o que não funciona é que o valor retornado é 1. E o total de registros dentro da tabela passa de 500.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código de `f_class_conecta_bd`

Comment: @perdeu eu não tenho acesso a conexão do banco, por isso não poderei lhe mostrar esse trecho.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18992/discussion-between-perdeu-and-alexandre).

Comment: Restrição de proxy -.- ! E sim, ser peixe pequeno na empresa é complicado!

Comment: O `print_r` retorna 1 ou um array com mais algumas chaves?

Comment: O `print_r` retorna 1

Comment: Veja se esse código muda o retorno:
`$w_querybusca = "SELECT COUNT (seq_elem) as total FROM \"Elem_matr\"";
        $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);
echo $w_queryresultado['total'];`

Comment: Esse trecho que você passou "anteriormente", não retorna nada, fica em branco!

Comment: Adicione essas duas linhas no inicio do arquivo e veja se aparece algum erro: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Já resolvi o problema, era uma determinada função do próprio `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: Não precisa colocar `resolvido` no título, pode marcar a resposta como aceita com `V`. [porque e como aceitar um resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/91)

Comment: É por causa que se a própria pessoa que perguntou respondeu. Só da para aceitar daqui 2 dias! Ai para não haver equivoco com quem visualizar essa pergunta, eu coloquei o resolvido. Mas daqui 2 dias eu edito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta para o meu caso era a falta de utilização de um comando do próprio `PostgreSQL`, que no caso ficaria assim:

```
   <?php
        $w_querybusca = "SELECT * FROM Elem_matr;";
        $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);

        $result = pg_num_rows($w_queryresultado);
        echo $result;        
    ?>
```